# How to exclude Meeting rooms and equipment from People Search Result?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, people-search

I'm trying to read people from the Office 365 sharepoint to build employee directory, using the Search REST API but it's listing Meeting rooms and Room Equipments also in the response. Even Graph API also return the same, I don't find any differentiation between Users and Groups in the result.
Is there any way to differentiate the Office 365 Resources and Users? Below is the url i use

https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/intranet/_api/search/query?querytext='*'&SourceId='B09A7990-05EA-4AF9-81EF-EDFAB16C4E31'

Comment: Have you had a look at the properties returned by the Sharepoint search query tool? I often use the HiddenFromExchangeAdressList property to filter out unwanted stuff

Comment: Hi @KasperBoLarsen, can you please send me some sample query for that?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I recall the excellent employee directory project includes that kind of filter, https://blog.hyperfish.com/employee-directory-in-office-365-and-sharepoint-?hs_amp=true
And it is a super easy way to save a lot of time